# Get Account Expiration date from active directory

Tags: java, datetime, attributes, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to convert Account Expires attribute of AD to date. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
    long adDate = Long.parseLong(adDateStr);
    long milliseconds = (adDate / 10000) - DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES;
    Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
    DateFormat mydate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return(mydate.format(date));
```

The problem is it is adding 1 day to the actual account expires day. 
e.g. if the account expires date is 08/01/2106 than the code above is giving 09/01/2016. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you convert long to new date() directly without manipulating?

Comment: no the 2nd line is necessary.

Comment: why this question is tagged under 'talend'? it's not related to TOS at all; i suggest an editing

Answer (score 1):

Just some guesses.

1. Is the value of DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATES = 11644473600000L + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000?
2. The time in accountExpires and the Date is UTC time (not local).
   Is this the reason?

Comment: accountExpires IS always UTC - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Probably some timezone shift and rounding strangeness.